# Where can I find Tech. ii. 128, 25?

Tags: old-english

Where can I find Tech. ii. 128, 25?
"Cyninges wífes tácen is þæt þú stréce onbútan heófod (run your hand round your head), and sete syððan þíne hand bufon þín heófod,"
 https://bosworthtoller.com/58648 ?
I only found "Techm." in the references http://ebeowulf.uky.edu/cgi-bin/Bosworth-Toller/ebind2html3.cgi/bosworth?seq=12

Comment: And when you tried looking in Techm., did it look like it might be the same or not?

Comment: I don't know how can look in Techm. ii. I only found https://dizzw.com/

Comment: Ask your library for https://books.google.cz/books/about/Internationale_Zeitschrift_F%C3%BCr_Allgemei.html?id=_avVuwEACAAJ&redir_esc=y or try to look for some online archives. I only found Band I at archive.org, but perhaps Band II is also somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I did the search myself. Band II is available at https://archive.org/details/internationaleze02techuoft/page/128/mode/2up

You want page 128, line 25.